# Mean number of subtractions in the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let n be a positive integer and let (a,b) be a randomly chosen pair of coprime positive integers such that a + b = n (meaning any such pair is equally likely to be chosen).  What can be said about the mean number of subtractions required to act the euclidean algorithm on the pair (a,b), and how does the answer behave as n increases?

Note it’s the number of subtractions I need to know about, and not the average number of lines in the algorithm when conducted by division.

Comment: This is basically asking for the expected sum of the coefficients of the continued fraction expansion of $\frac{a}{n-a}$ for $a$ drawn at random from $1,\dots,n/2$ (and restrcted to be coprime to $n$).  From the Gauss-Kuzmin distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kuzmin_distribution and the St Petersburg paradox analysis I would expect the answer to be $\asymp \log^2 n$, though rigorous analysis may be a little tricky.

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm doesn't go by subtractions, it goes by divisions with remainder. Anyway, it may be worthwhile having a look at Knuth's book, Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Seminumerical Algorithms, where he does a detailed analysis of Euclid and variants (if I remember right).

Comment: I have an algorithm for manufacturing n identical objects using two types of agents of differing speeds.  It is optimal in that they all work without an idle moment but they halt to exchange jobs once for every subtraction in the Euclidean algorithm (not just every line of the division), so I want to show there aren't too many:  my guess is order of the square of logn, which would be acceptable.  Haven't got a proof though.